# Why is my Android project not loading correctly in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

For some reason today my Android project is not loading up correctly in Eclipse. What I mean by not correctly is that usually I have src and gen at the top and now I have Android Dependencies at the top.

My src and gen folders are still there but it isn't loading up like it should. Almost as if it isn't recognizing the project type. This is an Android project that I have been working on for some time I just can't figure out why today its not loading correctly.

In my Android Build Path I have the following under Libraries.

```
Android 4.0.3
Android Dependencies
```

EDIT 1

Also, in my Console I am throwing this error.

```
/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
```

Comment: Try deleting the `gen` folder. Eclipse will recreate it when you compile your project.

Comment: You can also try to issue a cleanup on the Project from Eclipse.

Comment: Tried both of those solutions and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok well the gen folder recreated itself and looks like a package. However, src does not look like a package it just looks like a folder

Comment: Ok I was able to right click the src folder and go to Build Path... and then hit Use as source folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this ever happens to anyone you need to right click the src folder and go to Build Path->Use as source folder.

Then if your folders got out of order you can go to Build Path for the project and go to the Order & Export tab and then move the src and gen folder up and down.